# Bash input in the same line

Tags: bash, prompt

My server is a Debian distro. I am currently configuring this bad boy up.

In my Bash, I'm used to having the input to the command line being in one line, i.e.:

```
root@my-server:~    $  cd ..
```

However, in this server:

```
root@my-server:~#
cd ..
```

My question is - what configuration do I need to change to have my input in the same line?

EDIT:

This is one of the relevant things in my `.profile`:

```
force_color_prompt=yes                                                    

if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then                      
        export TERM='xterm-256color'                                      
else                                                                      
        export TERM='xterm-color'                                         
fi 

export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'                                          
eval "`dircolors`"
```

Comment: Whats the output of `echo "$PS1"` ?

Comment: `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

Comment: Are you logged in on the console or over the network? What terminal are you using? What is the output of `printf '%s\n' "$PS1" | hexdump` and of `echo "$TERM"?

Comment: Please show root's `PS1`.  The `PS1` that you claim is for a normal user.

Comment: Hi @John1024 - how do I show root's `PS1`?

Comment: Hi @Gilles - for `echo $TERM` - `echo $TERM
xterm-color`. For the hexdump - `0000000 7b24 6564 6962 6e61 635f 7268 6f6f 3a74
0000010 282b 6424 6265 6169 5f6e 6863 6f72 746f
0000020 7d29 5b5c 305c 3333 305b 3b31 3133 5c6d
0000030 5c5d 4075 685c 5b5c 305c 3333 305b 6d30
0000040 5d5c 5c3a 5c5b 3330 5b33 3130 333b 6d34
0000050 5d5c 775c 5b5c 305c 3333 305b 6d30 5d5c
0000060 245c 0a0a                              
0000064`. I am logged in over a DigitalOcean Droplet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PS1 variable most likely has a newline character in it. The variable is set whenever a new terminal is opened, when the bashrc is executed. So, to change it:

Open up the bashrc file:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Find the part where the PS1 variable is set. It should look something like this:

```
PS1="\\u@\\h:\\w#\n"
```

And remove the unwanted newline. In the case that you don't see a newline, your best bet is to replace the PS1 variable by putting this at the bottom of the bashrc file:

```
export PS1="\u@\h: \W\\#"
```

Comment: Hi therre. This is my `PS1` var: `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34‌​m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$` I do not see a `\n` in that.

Comment: Hmm, either there is some obfuscation, or a \n is being appended later in the file. See what happens if you put this at the _end_ of the bashrc file: `export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "`

Comment: @RandomPerson323 Note that the prompt that is causing the OP difficulty, as documented in the question, ends in `#`.  It, therefore, has nothing to do with the `PS1` prompt string that is being quoted in the comments which would display a `$`.

Comment: @RandomPerson323 that seemed to work! Now my input is `[root@bump ~]# `. There seems to be missing some color, however.

Comment: @faroskalin For the missing color, I recomend using a PS1 generator, such as: https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html There is an option to change the color.

Comment: @faroskalin Your hex dump shows that there's a newline character at the end of your `PS1` variable. It may have been written as `\n` or as `$'\n'` or as a newline character in the `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Random Person 323, I figured it out. Turns out my vim config forced my long `alias PS1='..'` into a new line, and so the ending `'` went to the next line on accident, and caused the issue.

This is what fixed it:

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]    $ '
```